# How to print logs by using ExtentReports listener in java?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, testng, extentreports

Here I am using the listener for generating reports in HTML format but it is not printing the logs present in a test case.

**Sample Test Cases**

```
@Test
public void testRedirectAllControlScreen() throws Exception {

    reportLog("login using a valid IsoMetrix username and password.");
    HomePage homePage = loginPage.login("username", "password");

    reportLog("Go to All Control page");
    AllControlPage allControlPage = homePage.navigateToControlPage();

    reportLog("Verify All Control page");
    allControlPage.verifyAllControlPage();

}
```

**Method Present in BaseClass**

```
 public void reportLog(String message) {
    message = BREAK_LINE + message;
    logger.info("Message: " + message);
    Reporter.log(message);
}
```

**ExtentReport Listener**

```
 public class ExtentReporterNG implements IReporter {

private ExtentReports extent;

public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory) {
    extent = new ExtentReports(outputDirectory + File.separator + "ExtentReport.html", true);

    for (ISuite suite : suites) {
        Map<String, ISuiteResult> result = suite.getResults();

        for (ISuiteResult r : result.values()) {
            ITestContext context = r.getTestContext();
            buildTestNodes(context.getPassedTests(), LogStatus.PASS);
            buildTestNodes(context.getFailedTests(), LogStatus.FAIL);
            buildTestNodes(context.getSkippedTests(), LogStatus.SKIP);
        }
    }

    extent.flush();
    extent.close();
}

private void buildTestNodes(IResultMap tests, LogStatus status) {
    ExtentTest test;

    if (tests.size() > 0) {
        for (ITestResult result : tests.getAllResults()) {
            test = extent.startTest(result.getMethod().getMethodName());
            test.assignAuthor("360Log");
            test.setStartedTime(getTime(result.getStartMillis()));
            test.setEndedTime(getTime(result.getEndMillis()));

            for (String group : result.getMethod().getGroups())
                test.assignCategory(group);
            int s = result.getStatus();
            if (result.getStatus() == 1) {
                test.log(status, "Test " + status.toString().toLowerCase() + "ed");
            } else {
                String screen = BaseTest.screen;
                test.log(status, "Test " + status.toString().toLowerCase() + "ed " + test.addScreenCapture(screen));

            }
            extent.endTest(test);
        }
    }
  }

}
```

PFA the screenshot. [image: It doesn't print logs step wise.]

Comment: what this does? Reporter.log(message);

Comment: @santhoshkumar it is default method provided by TestNG for logging.

Comment: Then we need to initiate the Extent test in before method and do logging as text.log(""); in @test method.

Comment: @santhoshkumar if we use that approach then what is the need of listener. I don't want to initialize exent test in BeforeMethod. That is the issue.

Comment: Yes agreed.. But that's the way if we need to add steps for each tests

Comment: I was going to add the "extent" tag to your post, but there's a five tag limit.  Since this is the main topic of your post, you should consider deleting one of the other tags in lieu of extent.  I realize it's not a big group, but its more likely to have a member/follower with an answer.  I've only just started using extent reports myself.

Answer (score 4):

Without using listener I am able to achieve the same thing.
I implemented the extent test and extent report in **Baseclass.java** as per people suggestion like this:

```
public static ExtentTest test;
public static ExtentReports extent;

@BeforeSuite
public void before() {
    extent = new ExtentReports("target\\surefire-reports\\ExtentReport.html", true);
}

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp(Method method) throws Exception {
            test = extent.startTest(method.getClass().getSimpleName(),method.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName());
    test.assignAuthor("Vaibhav");
//Rest code will be generic for browser initiliazion.

}

@AfterSuite
public void tearDownSuite() {
    // reporter.endReport();
    extent.flush();
    extent.close();
}

//Method for adding logs passed from test cases
 public void reportLog(String message) {    
    test.log(LogStatus.INFO, message);//For extentTest HTML report
    logger.info("Message: " + message);
    Reporter.log(message);

}
```

**Sample Test Case**

```
@Test
public void testRedirectAllControlScreen() throws Exception {

    reportLog("login using a valid IsoMetrix username and password.");
    HomePage homePage = loginPage.login("username", "password");

    reportLog("Go to All Control page");
    AllControlPage allControlPage = homePage.navigateToControlPage();

    reportLog("Verify All Control page");
    allControlPage.verifyAllControlPage();

}
```

- **ExtentReport view**

[image: ExtentReport view]

Answer (score 2):

The Below Code Works for me for Extent Report version : v2.41.1, Try it!!!

Try Creating an Object of Extent Report and logger as the Below Code.

```
// Base Class Usage
public static ExtentReports report;
public static ExtentTest logger;

report = new ExtentReports(path);       
report.loadConfig(new File("//home//.....//extent-config.xml"));

logger = report.startTest(this.getClass().getSimpleName()).assignCategory("Happy Path"));

// Test Case Usage: Using it at Every Step in Each Test Case
 logger.log(LogStatus.INFO,"String Message to Log for Each Step in Test Case");

// @AfterMethod
@AfterMethod(alwaysRun=true)
  public void TearDown_AM(ITestResult result) throws IOException
  {
      System.out.println("@After Method");
    try
    { 
        if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.FAILURE)
        {
            String res = captureScreenshot(Driver, result.getName());
            String image= logger.addScreenCapture(res);
            System.out.println(image);
            String TestCaseName = this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " Test Case Failure and Title/Boolean Value Failed";
            logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, TestCaseName  + logger.addScreenCapture(res));
            //  logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, image, this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " Test Case Failure and Title/Boolean Value Failed");
        }
        else if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.SUCCESS)
        {
            logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " Test Case Success and Title Verified"); 
        }
        else if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.SKIP)
        {
            logger.log(LogStatus.SKIP, this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " Test Case Skipped");
        }
        report.endTest(logger);
        report.flush();

    }
    catch(Throwable t)
    {
        logger.log(LogStatus.ERROR,t.fillInStackTrace());
    }

  }
```

[image: Logging in Extent Report Test Case Wise]

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is little old but might help someone.
Use this code for buildTestNodes method to print TestNG logs - Reporter.log().

```
public void buildTestNodes(IResultMap tests, LogStatus status) {
        //ExtentTest test = null;
        if (tests.size() > 0) {
            List<ITestResult> resultList = new LinkedList<ITestResult>(tests.getAllResults());
            class ResultComparator implements Comparator<ITestResult> {
                public int compare(ITestResult r1, ITestResult r2) {
                    return getTime(r1.getStartMillis()).compareTo(getTime(r2.getStartMillis()));
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(resultList , new ResultComparator ());

            for (ITestResult result : resultList) {
                test = extent.startTest(result.getMethod().getMethodName());
                test.getTest().setDescription(result.getMethod().getDescription());
                test.getTest().setStartedTime(getTime(result.getStartMillis()));
                test.getTest().setEndedTime(getTime(result.getEndMillis()));
                for(String message:Reporter.getOutput(result)){    **//This code picks the log from Reporter object.**
                    test.log(LogStatus.INFO, message);
                }
                for (String group : result.getMethod().getGroups())
                test.assignCategory(group);
                String message = "Test " + status.toString().toLowerCase() + "ed";
                if (result.getThrowable() != null)
                message = result.getThrowable().getClass() +": "+ result.getThrowable().getMessage();
                test.log(status, message);
                extent.endTest(test);
            }
        }
    }
```