# Extent report logs for Test Steps is not working

Tags: extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I have a TestNG test that has multiple methods. The extent report works in the main class but when I try to write logs for the other methods I am getting null pointer exception. All the tutorials point to writing logs in the main method but not to the other methods. I have been struggling to find a solution for this for a week now. Can somebody help me please ? Thanks

My code is some thing like this

```
@Test
public void TestOne()
{
extentTest = extent.startTest("TestOne");
Login.LoginToClient();
Access.AccessMainPage();
-
-
}


Public void LoginToClient()

{
  ***How can write an extent report log here for example - "Enter Username"
  driver.findElement(By.id("username")).SendKeys(username)
  -
  -
}
```

The following is written in the main test

```html
@BeforeTest
 public void setExtent(){
  extent = new ExtentReports(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/test-output/ExtentReport.html", true);
  extent.addSystemInfo("Host Name", "Calcutta");
  extent.addSystemInfo("User Name", "Admin");
  extent.addSystemInfo("Environment", "QA");  
 }
 
 @AfterMethod
 public void tearDown(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
  
  if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.FAILURE){
   
   //to add name in extent report
   extentTest.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "TEST CASE FAILED IS "+result.getName()); 
    //to add error/exception in extent report
   extentTest.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "TEST CASE FAILED IS "+result.getThrowable());
   String screenshotPath = Screenshots.getScreenshot(driver, result.getName());
   //to add screenshot in extent report
   extentTest.log(LogStatus.FAIL, extentTest.addScreenCapture(screenshotPath)); 
   
  }
  else if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.SKIP){
   extentTest.log(LogStatus.SKIP, "Test Case SKIPPED IS " + result.getName());
  }
  else if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.SUCCESS){
   extentTest.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Test Case PASSED IS " + result.getName());
  }
  extent.endTest(extentTest); 
 }
```

My Full code is here

```html
package yellowfin.bi.test;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import y.bi.create.reports.charts.ContentMenuButton;
import y.bi.create.reports.charts.ReportChartBuilder;
import y.bi.create.reports.charts.ReportFormattingPage;
import y.bi.create.reports.charts.ViewForReport;
import y.bi.login.loginPage;
import y.bi.logout.Logout;
import y.bi.screenshots.Screenshots;
import y.bi.utils.Printscreen;
import y.bi.utils.BrowserFactory;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

public class ReportFormatting {
 private EventFiringWebDriver driver;
 private loginPage login;
 private Logout logout;
 private ContentMenuButton createContentMenuButton;
 private ViewForReport reportView;
 private ReportChartBuilder createChart;
 Printscreen ps;
 private ReportFormattingPage reportFormattingPage;
 public ExtentReports extent;
 public ExtentTest logger;

 
 @BeforeSuite(enabled = true)
 public void setUpTheTest() {
  driver = (EventFiringWebDriver) BrowserFactory.selectBrowser("chrome");
 }
 
 @Parameters({ "yellowfinURL" })
 @BeforeTest(enabled = true)
 public void instantiatePages(String url) {
  driver.get(url);
  login = new loginPage(driver);
  logout = new Logout(driver);
  createContentMenuButton = new ContentMenuButton(driver);
  reportView = new ViewForReport(driver);
  createChart = new ReportChartBuilder(driver);
  ps = new Printscreen(driver);
  reportFormattingPage = new ReportFormattingPage(driver);
  
 }
 
 @BeforeTest
 public void setExtent(){
  extent = new ExtentReports(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/test-output/ExtentReport.html", true);
  extent.addSystemInfo("Host Name", "Calcutta");
  extent.addSystemInfo("User Name", "Admin");
  extent.addSystemInfo("Environment", "QA");  
 }

 
 
 @AfterMethod(alwaysRun=true)
   public void TearDown_AM(ITestResult result) throws IOException
   {
       System.out.println("@After Method");
     try
     { 
         if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.FAILURE)
         {
          String screenshotPath = Screenshots.getScreenshot(driver, result.getName());
             String image= logger.addScreenCapture(screenshotPath);
             System.out.println(image);
             String TestCaseName = this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " Test Case Failure and Title/Boolean Value Failed";
             logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, TestCaseName  + logger.addScreenCapture(screenshotPath));
             
         }
         else if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.SUCCESS)
         {
             logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " Test Case Success"); 
         }
         else if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.SKIP)
         {
             logger.log(LogStatus.SKIP, this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " Test Case Skipped");
         }
         extent.endTest(logger);
         extent.flush();

     }
     catch(Throwable t)
     {
         logger.log(LogStatus.ERROR,t.fillInStackTrace());
     }

   }
 
 
 @Parameters({ "userName", "passsword", "viewName", "rf1", "rf2", "rf3", "rf4", "rf5", "fontType" ,"fontSize"})
 @Test(testName = "validateDataSection", enabled = true, groups = {"Report Formatting : Data"}, alwaysRun = true, priority=1)
 public void ValidateDataSection(String username, String password, String viewName, String r1, String r2, String r3, String r4, String r5, String ftype, String fsize)  {
 
  logger = extent.startTest("ValidateDataSection");
  
         
  login.loginToTenant(username, password);
  // select view from content menu button
  createContentMenuButton.setContentMenuButton();
  // choose view
  reportView.selectView(viewName);
  // create the report in report builder
  createChart.createReport(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5);
  
  //Checks the style "Font Type, Font Size, Bold Italic"
  reportFormattingPage.DataSection(ftype,fsize);
  
  // Access Row Highlight
  reportFormattingPage.RowHighlight();
  
     logout.performLogout();
  

 }
 
 
 @Parameters({ "userName", "passsword", "viewName", "rf1", "rf2", "rf3", "rf4", "rf5", "headerFontType", "headerFontSize", "borderWidth"})
 @Test(testName = "Validate Column & Row Headings and Border", enabled = false, groups = {"Report Formatting : Column & Row Headings and Border"}, alwaysRun = true, priority=1)
 public void ValidateColumnandRowHeadingsandBorder(String username, String password, String viewName, String r1, String r2, String r3, String r4, String r5, String headerFontType, String headerFontSize, String borderWidth) {
  logger = extent.startTest("ValidateColumnandRowHeadingsandBorder");
  
   
  login.loginToTenant(username, password);
  // select view from content menu button
  createContentMenuButton.setContentMenuButton();
  // choose view
  reportView.selectView(viewName);
  // create the report in report builder
  createChart.createReport(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5);
  
  // validates the column and Row headings
  reportFormattingPage.ColumnAndRowHandling(headerFontType, headerFontSize);
  
  // Validates the border
  reportFormattingPage.Border(borderWidth);
  
  logout.performLogout();

 }
 
 @Parameters({ "userName", "passsword", "viewName", "rf1", "rf2", "rf3", "rf4", "rf5", "displayTitleFontType", "displayTitleFontSize", "displayDescFontType", "displayDescFontSize"})
 @Test(testName = "Validate Title and Description", enabled = false, groups = {"Report Formatting : Title and Description"}, alwaysRun = true, priority=1)
 public void ValidateTitleandDescription(String username, String password, String viewName, String r1, String r2, String r3, String r4, String r5, String displayTitleFontType, String displayTitleFontSize, String displayDescFontType, String displayDescFontSize)  {
  logger = extent.startTest("ValidateTitleandDescription");
    
  login.loginToTenant(username, password);
  // select view from content menu button
  createContentMenuButton.setContentMenuButton();
  // choose view
  reportView.selectView(viewName);
  // create the report in report builder
  createChart.createReport(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5);
  
  //Validates Title and Description
  reportFormattingPage.TitleAndDescription(displayTitleFontType,displayTitleFontSize,displayDescFontType,displayDescFontSize);
  
  logout.performLogout();

 }
 
 

 @Parameters({ "userName", "passsword", "viewName", "rf1", "rf2", "rf3", "rf4", "rf5", "displayTitleFontType", "displayTitleFontSize", "displayDescFontType", "displayDescFontSize"})
 @Test(testName = "Validate header / Footer and Table sort", enabled = false, groups = {"Report Formatting : header / Footer and Table sort"}, alwaysRun = true, priority=1)
 public void ValidateHeaderFooterandTableSort(String username, String password, String viewName, String r1, String r2, String r3, String r4, String r5, String displayTitleFontType, String displayTitleFontSize, String displayDescFontType, String displayDescFontSize)  {
  
  logger = extent.startTest("ValidateHeaderFooterandTableSort");
   
  login.loginToTenant(username, password);
  // select view from content menu button
  createContentMenuButton.setContentMenuButton();
  // choose view
  reportView.selectView(viewName);
  // create the report in report builder
  createChart.createReport(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5);
  
  //Validates Header and Footer page
  reportFormattingPage.HeaderAndFooter();
  
  //Validates Table sort
  reportFormattingPage.TableSort();
  logout.performLogout();
  

 }
 
 @AfterTest
 public void endReport(){
  extent.flush();
  extent.close();
  driver.quit();
 }
 
}
```

```html
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;

import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

import yellowfin.bi.screenshots.Screenshots;


public class ReportFormattingPage {
 static WebDriver driver;
 static long d = 2000;
 String xpathElements="//div[@class='toggleSwitchSliderInner']";  
 String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
 ReportFormat rf = new ReportFormat();
 SoftAssert sa= new SoftAssert();
 Screenshots screenshot = new Screenshots();
 public ExtentReports extent;
 public ExtentTest logger;
 
 @BeforeTest
 public void setExtent(){
  extent = new ExtentReports(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/test-output/ExtentReport.html", true);
  extent.addSystemInfo("Host Name", "Calcutta");
  extent.addSystemInfo("User Name", "Admin");
  extent.addSystemInfo("Environment", "QA");  
 }
 
 @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
 public ReportFormattingPage(WebDriver driver) {
 
  this.driver = driver;
 } 
 
 public void DataSection(String FontType, String FontSize) 

 {
  
  try {
       logger = extent.startTest("ValidateDataSection");   
    //Click on Report Format
       logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Access Report Format Button");
    rf.accessReportFormat(driver);
    //Click on the Toggle switch
    
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.toggleSwitchSliderInner")).click();
    Thread.sleep(d);
    //Select the font type
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.fontDropDown > div.styledSelect.customSelect > select"))).selectByVisibleText(FontType);
    Thread.sleep(d);
    //Select the font size
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.broadcastInput")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.broadcastInput")).sendKeys(FontSize);
    //Click on Bold
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.fontStyleOptions > div > img")).click();
    Thread.sleep(d);
    //Select italic and underline
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='images/format_italic.png']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='images/format_underline.png']")).click();
       
    //Changing the color of the text
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='sp-preview-inner']")).click();      
    rf.dragAndDrop(driver);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@id='chooseColourText'])")).click();
    //Row shading Default
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(), 'Default')]")).click();
    // Row Shading Alternative ------------------------------------------------------------
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(), 'Alternating')]")).click();
    //click on the Alternate Row Color  
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[contains(text(), 'Define a color to be applied to every second row in the table.')]//following::div[@class='backboneColourPicker'])[1]")).click();
    //Select the color  
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@style='background-color:rgb(143, 80, 157);'])[3]")).click();
    // Click on close and access the design page
    rf.clickCloseAndAccessDesignPage(driver);
    Thread.sleep(d);
    screenshot.captureScreenShot(driver, "RowShadingAlternative");
    //Click on Report Format
    rf.accessReportFormat(driver);
    //RowShading none ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(), 'None')]")).click();
    // Click on close and access the design page
       rf.clickCloseAndAccessDesignPage(driver);
       screenshot.captureScreenShot(driver, "RowShadingNone");
    //Click on Report Format
    rf.accessReportFormat(driver);
    rf.clickCloseAndAccessDesignPage(driver);
    //Assertions
    rf.DataSectionAssertions(driver);
    Thread.sleep(d); 
    screenshot.captureScreenShot(driver, "RowShadingDefault");
 
 }
 
 catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
 
 }
 
    
 public void RowHighlight() 
    
    {  
  
  try {
      //Click on Report Format
      rf.accessReportFormat(driver);
      // Click on the toggle switch for the Row Highlight field
      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.controlContainer > div.toggleSwitchSlider > div.toggleSwitchSliderInner")).click();
      // Click on Row Highlight color
      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.sp-preview-inner.no-colour")).click();
      // Select the color
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@style='background-color:rgb(124, 187, 0);'])[3]")).click();
      // Click on close and access the design page
      rf.clickCloseAndAccessDesignPage(driver);
      Robot robot = new Robot();
      robot.mouseMove(200,600);
      robot.delay(1500);
      robot.mouseMove(200,900);
      Thread.sleep(d);
      screenshot.captureScreenShot(driver, "RowHighlight");
 
    }
  
 catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
```

Comment: Please share sample code of trial, in which it is working. How and Where you have define it ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please see the code above. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check these links for the answer:

- [How to print logs by using ExtentReports listener in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44542760/how-to-print-logs-by-using-extentreports-listener-in-java)
- https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/EmailableReporter2.java

If you have a Reporting Class say which Listens to the TestNG Listner and have ExtentReport code implemented in it you can get the TestCase Steps using Reporter Object
please see below.

Note that Reporter .log of TestNG does not have any definition for Type of Log like INFO, FATAL etc.. It just adds the Log Message.

*Test case:*

```
public class TC_1 extends BaseClass{
    @Test (priority=0)
    public void addNotes()  throws Exception  
    {   
        if (super.search("VALUE"))
        {
            logger.info("Search is Successful");
            Reporter.log("Search is Successful");
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
        }
     }
```

*Reporting:*

```
public class Reporting extends TestListenerAdapter
{
public ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
    public ExtentReports extent;
    public ExtentTest logger;
public void onStart(ITestContext testContext)
    {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());//time stamp
        String repName="Test-Report-"+timeStamp+".html";

        htmlReporter=new ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/test-output/"+repName);//specify location of the report
        htmlReporter.loadXMLConfig(System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/extent-config.xml");

        extent=new ExtentReports();

        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

        htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Test Project"); 
        htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Functional Test Automation Report"); 
        htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP); 
        htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);
    }

public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult tr)
    {
        logger=extent.createTest(tr.getName()); 
        logger.log(Status.PASS,MarkupHelper.createLabel(tr.getName(),ExtentColor.GREEN)); 

List<String> reporterMessages = Reporter.getOutput(tr);
                for (int i = 0; i < reporterMessages.size(); i++) 
            {
                    System.out.println(reporterMessages.get(i));
                    logger.info(reporterMessages.get(i)); 
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I recommend to use [Version 3](http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/#examples) instead of Version 2,

As I can see in your Code, You have define Test definition but there is no such logs for that method in which you wants to generate,

Please Refer as Following, to generate logs:

You can use same way in any method,

```
extentTest.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Test Case Details");
```

Here object of ExtentTest need to declare as Class variable, So you can access it anywhere within class.

If you wants to create different Test section for `Login.LoginToClient();` method, you can define it like:

```
Public void LoginToClient()
{  
  extentTest = extent.startTest("Login Test");

  driver.findElement(By.id("username")).SendKeys(username);

  extentTest.log(LogStatus.INFO, "User Name: " +username);  
}
```

Hope it will works as you want to generate.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I am getting null pointer exception

Comment: Include the code where you have define it ExtentTest Object, Is everything in single class ?

Comment: It is not in a single class.

Comment: So you have to define object first and then start to create test.
ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports("file-path");        
ExtentTest test = extent.startTest("My Test");

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I have put my entire code. The first piece of code is the main test and the second one is the bunch of methods where I want to put my extent report logs. I have done exactly what you have said, however it doesn't seem to be printing the logs

Comment: I am not understanding, Where you are stuck ? Now, if NullPointerException gone what is happening next, If log is not printing what is breakpoint of it ? Please share error stack trace,

Comment: There is no null pointer exception anymore. System does not print logs for the above piece of code. The main test call this function DataSection. Hope it makes sense

Comment: @BobJones Please debug execution, So you will get value where you find null value. Its easy to track for you and difficult for me to assume. Your extentTest is getting assigned with ExtentReport but some how class has null value of driver, As far I see. So Debug it and you will get idea.