# Customized Report in testng , need to print massage in report

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Im not able to print massage in Customized Testng Report which i generated from Code, But when i use Reporter.log(); it will show the massage in default report which are e-mailable.I attached the Two diffrent reeport which are defult generated by testng and other one is i created by code.

[image]

[image]

I need to print massage in my costamized report.

Comment: Please, provide a minimal, reproducible example: 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Since you posted the extent reports screenshot, I am assuming that you already implemented ExtentReports in your project. If that is the case, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44542760/how-to-print-logs-by-using-extentreports-listener-in-java for existing solutions.